# How do I plot a parametric equation in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, graphing

I've looked at the matplotlib example of parametric equations to try and plot my own equation in xyz-coordinates. Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is plot the z, y, and x variables as I plotted below but it's giving me this weird error message:

TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()

Still new to Python so don't really understand what the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Further clarification*: I'm trying to plot this function as a variable of t from 1 to 9

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

v = 33
t = np.linspace(1,10,1)
theta = np.pi/9
h = 2

# Prepare arrays x, y, z
z = 1
x = v*t*np.cos(theta)
y = -16*t**2 + v*t*np.sin(theta) + h



ax.plot(x, y, z, label='parametric curve')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: z is a scalar; as your comment says, you need an array.

Comment: I've run your code and I don't get the error. What line are you getting the error on? Also, I would recommend changing t to `np.linspace(1, 10, 100)` because having the last argument as 1 will draw a point instead of a line.

Comment: change `z=1` to `z = np.ones(t.shape)`